# registration app code is not working

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I am trying to enter data of user in online database using a app but data is not inserting in database. Php file is correct it is inserting data but my app is not here is my register.java file code.
package net.netai.hackt_swg.microbok;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e_name,e_ml,e_ps;
    String name,email,pas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button reg;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rgs);
        e_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        e_ml=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mls);
        e_ps=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pss);
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rg();
            }
        });
    }
    public void rg(){
        name=e_name.getText().toString();
        email=e_ml.getText().toString();
        pas=e_ps.getText().toString();

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
        backgroundTask.execute(name,email,pas);
        finish();
    }


    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,String> {

        String reg_URL;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            reg_URL="http://hackt_swg.netai.net/app/register.php";

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            String nm=params[0];
            String em=params[1];
            String ps=params[2];
            try {
                URL url=new URL(reg_URL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data= URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(nm,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(em,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(ps,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream in=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                in.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "registration successful";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return  "null";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

and my MainActivity.java is

```
package net.netai.hackt_swg.microbok;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button lgn,sgnup;
    EditText e_password,e_email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lgn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        sgnup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);

        e_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mail);
        e_password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {

        }
        else{
            lgn.setEnabled(false);
            sgnup.setEnabled(false);
            e_password.setEnabled(false);
            e_email.setEnabled(false);
        }
        lgn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        sgnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                p();
            }
        });
    }
    public void p(){
        Intent i=new Intent( this ,register.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

register.php

```
   <?php
$hostname="mysql13.000webhost.com";
$mysqlusername="a1544527_danzen";
$mysqlpassword="********";
$databasename = "a1544527_appData";
$db=mysqli_connect($hostname,$mysqlusername,$mysqlpassword,$databasename) or die("noooooo");

$fname=$_POST['name'];

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];




mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO user (name,password,email) VALUES(
'". mysqli_escape_string($db,$fname) ."', 
'". mysqli_escape_string($db,md5($password)) ."', 
'". mysqli_escape_string($db,$email) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());

    echo 'successfully registered';                     


?>
```

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You user this code in your project please ready [Okhttp](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp) lib to send data to server.When you use this code then call this method and then call this method but be careful about.

```
public void Register(String nm, String em, String pm)
{
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("name", nm)
                    .add("email", em)
                    .add("password", pm)
                    .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://hackt_swg.netai.net/app/register.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Get Api Credentials Request Failed " + call.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
                {
                    String responseUser = response.body().string().toString();
                    Lor.i("[Registration]", ""+responseUser);
                }
      });
}
```

Comment: Still not working and returning null. It is not going in try i think.

Comment: Thank you for your code.But now my previous code is working.Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad to help you.please up vote so other can get help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the url. Check your url: http://hackt_swg.netai.net/app/register.php Also I recommed use Retrofit. It's the best way of web service

Comment: if you want retrofit, I can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help but now my code is working.So thanks a lot